# Survival model for longitudinal data with overlapping exposures

Tags: survival, frailty

I have a dataset with info on patient exposures (drug 1 / drug 2) and outcomes (hospitalisation / death) over ten years.  All patients were prescribed drug 1 on and off over the period (inclusion criteria for the study), and some patients were prescribed drug 2.

I am interested in modelling patient survival in R, including time to hospitalisation and time to death.  My hypothesis is that being prescribed drug 2 (alone or in combination with drug 1) increases the risk of these outcomes.  I had intended to develop a joint frailty model using the *frailtypack* library as this would account for the longitudinal nature of the data, repeat drug 1 treatment episodes, and include individual factors associated with risk of outcome.

Although drug 2 is my main exposure of interest, I would like to explore drug 1 as a contributory factor, but am not sure if this is appropriate / feasible in a frailty model.

Should I create a 4-state dummy variable {no drugs, drug 1 alone, drug 2 alone, drug 1 + drug 2} and use this as my exposure variable?  Would a different modelling approach be more suitable for these data?

[image: Visual description of patient data]

Answer (score 1):

Your 4-state dummy variable (with a baseline level subsumed in the baseline hazard so that you only code 3 dummies) is what you would get if you included a term `drug 1 * drug 2` in your R formula. That's certainly a way to proceed, although I prefer to let R expand my formulas for me. The presence of the drugs would be coded as time-varying covariates.

The question is just what you intend to model. With that type of term in a proportional hazards model you are evaluating how much the presence of either or both of the drugs affects the risks of events *instantaneously*. If you think that any prior exposure to `drug 1` or the cumulative exposure to `drug 1` is what really matters with respect to event probability directly or to affecting responses to `drug 2`, you need to provide corresponding time-varying covariate values associated with `drug 1`.